# How to debug slow Android Async response after it queries remote server and updates the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-asynctask

I have an android app which use the same server PHP scripts to do something in the database and respond back, and then update thee screen accordingly.

About 60% of the time it is fast. But sometimes the ui of the phone hangs for a long time and it is really confusing to users because they think something is wrong.

Also if the app screen hangs for a long time, i just referesh it, and I see that the data is all there so the problem is after the data is inserted into the db.

Here is my Android code:

I have an TopicActivity which extends BaseListActivity which extends ListActivity

In TopicActivity I first set up the list like this:

```
DiscussionMessage d = new DiscussionMessage ();
d.setMessage( "Please wait while the discussion load..." );

discussion.add(d);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<DiscussionMessage>( 
        this,R.layout.discussion_comments, 
        discussion);

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

then when something happens I call the sendFeedback method which looks like this:

```
public void sendFeedback( String c , String user_id , String problem_id , 
        String recent_topic_id )
{  
    String[] params = new String[] 
            { "the_remote_url", 
             c , user_id, problem_id , recent_topic_id };

    AddComment task = new AddComment();
    task.execute(params);        
}
```

Then here is how the AddComment class looks like.  It is inside the TopicActivity class:

```
public class AddComment extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... theParams) 
    {
        String myUrl = theParams[0];
        final String comment = theParams[1];
        final String user_id = theParams[2];
        final String problem_id = theParams[3];
        final String recent_topic_id = theParams[4];

        String charset = "UTF-8";           
        String response = null;

        try 
        {                           
            String query = String.format("comment=%s&user_id=%s&problem_id=%s&recent_topic_id=%s", 
                     URLEncoder.encode( comment, charset), 
                     URLEncoder.encode( user_id, charset), 
                     URLEncoder.encode( problem_id, charset), 
                     URLEncoder.encode( recent_topic_id, charset)
                     );             

            final URL url = new URL( myUrl + "?" + query );

            final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(true); 
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);

            conn.connect();

            InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
            byte[] stream_buffer = new byte[8196];
            int readCount;
            StringBuilder stream_builder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((readCount = stream.read(stream_buffer)) > -1) 
            {
                stream_builder.append(new String(stream_buffer, 0, readCount));
            }

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {

        if ( result != null )
        {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not get the current discussion.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                
        }
        else
        {               
            try
            {
                JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(result);

                if ( obj != null )
                {
                    discussion.clear();

                    if ( obj.length() == 0 )
                    {
                        DiscussionMessage message = new DiscussionMessage ( );
                        message.setMessage("No messages in this discussion.");

                        discussion.add( message );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for ( int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++ )
                        {
                            JSONObject o = obj.getJSONObject(i);

                            String comment = o.getString("comment");
                            String commenter_id = o.getString("commenter_id");
                            String comment_id = o.getString("comment_id");
                            String first_name = o.getString("first_name");
                            String last_name = o.getString("last_name");
                            String is_private = o.getString("is_private");

                            DiscussionMessage d = new DiscussionMessage ( );
                            d.setMessage(comment);
                            d.setAuthorId(commenter_id);
                            d.setMessageId(comment_id); 
                            d.setAuthorName(first_name);                                

                            discussion.add( d );
                        }
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

                    // Now clear the text area of text.
                    EditText comment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.discussion_comment);  
                    comment.setText( "" );  
                }                   
            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                   // Do something.
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Is it possible to tell from this what I may be doing wrong? Is it an issue with how I use Async or the ListAdapter maybe?

Ideas for fixing and/or debugging this are much appreciated!

Comment: Sir, Log.d() is a great function. It might be helpful to know where it is failing. Insert some Log.d() statements in order to find the where the problem occurs. Then it *should* be much easier to help you. Also, if you *are* getting an error in onPostExecute(), according to your code, nothing is happening, you might dump that to the log in order to debug more effectively.

Comment: @FuzzicalLogic I do have it, but I took those statements out for this question. I can not reproduce the slowness on the simulator, just on the live phone. Also, it doesn't fail, it eventually loads, just sometimes after a very very long time.

Comment: A clarification then: Does this happen only after the application has been running for awhile? or can it happen right at the start of the application?

Comment: @FuzzicalLogic it happens any time during the running of the program. Although I am not sure if I get out of the program on my phone, it means it is totally off.  It migth still be running in the background which confuses my answer to you :)

Comment: Well, I happen to know that AsyncTask will start to behave strangely when you get beyond a certain point (5 or more, less on some devices). But I'm not sure if its relevant. There is some documentation on it. Let me see if I can find it and maybe you can determine its relevancy. Otherwise, if it is not failing and you have logs, then I'm not sure where else to start.

Answer (score 2):

Move your JSON parsing and creation of the `DiscussionMessage` objects to `doInBackground()`, as they will take time and should run on the background thread. Leave pouring the `DiscussionMessage` objects into the `Adapter` and calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onPostExecute()`.

Beyond that, as Fuzzical Logic points out, you need to determine precisely where your difficulty lies, whether using `Log` calls or Traceview or whatever. For example, is it that your Web service is sometimes slow to respond?

Comment: interesting.  What is the main difference of doing the parsing in the onPostExecute vs. doInBackground? I thought onPostExecute executes on the phone after the result comes back, and it the simplest way as its just parsing strings?  Is it a very inefficient way of doing things?

Comment: @GeekedOut: The complete and entire point behind `AsyncTask` is to move long-running work off of the main application thread and put it on a background thread, while still making it convenient for you to update the UI from the main application thread as needed. While you may think "its just parsing strings", that may take some time, depending upon the size of the JSON, particularly given that you are using `JSONObject` (not especially speedy). The goal is to have as few lines of code in `onPostExecute()` as possible, to maximize the benefit of the background thread.